# Is there a SL4J logging library for .net?

Tags: .net, logging

In java, there is a library called SL4J that "wraps" several different logging implementations (default jdk, log4j, commons logging etc.) and makes it quite easy to replace the logging implementation without any code changes.

Is there such a library for .net?

Comment: I thought that commons logging already was a library that wraps several logging implementations? At least, that's how I use it in a .NET project I'm currently working on.

Comment: You're right, in java it is. I got them confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a logging facade for the .NET world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733510/is-there-a-logging-facade-for-the-net-world)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Common Infrastructure Libraries for .NET](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) provide such an infrastructure for logging.

It supports full bi-directional event routing support for Entlib 3.1, EntLib 4.1, log4net 1.2.9, log4net 1.2.10 and NLog logging

Comment: Thank you, that's the sort of thing I was looking for.
Do you have good experiences with it in production?

Comment: @Sebastian: No, sorry. I don´t use it.

Comment: I used it on two of my projects and can recommend it. Very similar to log4net in syntax.   
The only objection is - how difficult would it really be to replace the logging library without the added abstraction of common.logging?

Answer (score 0):

Use Log4Net, as it has a lot of appenders, also for other logging libaries, like the standard .net event log.
most times the most easiest and useful one.

Comment: That's the one we're using now. I'd like to be able to "camouflage" it and be able to replace it at a later date in case something better comes along

Comment: hmm... but than its only worth, if it has a better interface.
in our case, we created our own "camouflage", with a pretty nice fluent interface. and some automatic context detection.