# .Net Logger using DLL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dll, dependency-injection, nlog, logging

I'm creating a site using .Net 4.0 and C# with the MVC2 Framework.

I have 5 different projects under the solution - AdminPresentation, FrontEndPresentation, DataAccessLayer, Business, Tests.

I'm looking to implement a logger that can be used throughout all the layers and was advised that it might be best to include the Logger classes as a Dll and include this in my projects.
I'm going to use nLog but I suppose it should be be possible to slot a different logger in if needed (Dependency injection?).

I am new to .NET/C#, any advice/examples/links to sites would be very much appreciated, Specifically how to implement the logger and how to use it as a dll if appropriate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many logger abstractions available, no need to roll your own, see [Is there a logging facade for the .NET world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733510/is-there-a-logging-facade-for-the-net-world)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `ILogger` interface and use that throughout your application. In your DI configuration you map the `ILogger` to a type that knows how to send messages to NLog.